# Apex Security rule Check of Soql/ DML

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, security, field-level-security, pmd

Trying to add Security Check on SOQL/ DML action in my Apex class.

Gone through the following link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_security_sharing_chapter.htm

**1) Enforcing Object and Field Permissions**

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isAccessible()) {
Contact c = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id= :Id];
}
```

**2) Enforce Security With the stripInaccessible Method**

```
List<Account> accounts =
[SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account];
SObjectAccessDecision decision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE,accounts);
```

**3) Filter SOQL Queries Using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED**

```
List<Account> act = [SELECT Id, Name  FROM Account WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]
```

On Above three Security check Which is the right rule to use for security check of Object and Field level, In my class i have SOQL query and  DML action

Comment: Without more context this cannot be answered (factually, at least) because the features you use depend on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The first method (describe calls) is the old-school way of checking permissions. This works, but can be cumbersome if there are many fields/objects involved. WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED is advisable if any missing permissions should halt the process, as it throws an exception on failure. Security.stripInaccessible is preferred for most other use cases, as it allows you to programmatically decide if you want to continue based on which fields/records/objects the user has access to. This is probably the method you should use in most cases.